# How to thread this simple scanner

Tags: python, multithreading, port

I need a little help on my port scanner in Python. I have to learn how to add the `threading` module to it, but have no clue and do not really understand the few tutorials and help I've found. Here is a little test script:

```
from socket import *

remote = raw_input ("Website: ")
remote_ip = gethostbyname(remote)

print "scaning at:",remote_ip
for i in range (20,100):
    s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    result = s.connect_ex((remote,i))
    if result == 0):
        print "port %d: open"%(i)
    s.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below.  You force each function into a separate thread and kick it off.  You also keep a reference to each thread so you can block your main thread until they have all executed.  You also need a lock because "print" in Python isn't thread safe and you'll end up getting the output from each thread mangled up otherwise (you can use the logger instead which is thread safe and neater).  This will also generate a lot of threads as I haven't even bothered to show you pooling.  This is just a rough and ready example to get you going on your journey to discover multi threading in Python.

```
print_lock = Lock()


def socket_test(address, port):
    s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    result = s.connect_ex((address,port))
    if result == 0:
        with print_lock:
            print "port %s: open" % port
    s.close()


def main():
    remote = raw_input("Website: ")
    remote_ip = gethostbyname(remote)
    print "scaning at:",remote_ip
    threads = []
    for i in range(20, 100):
        new_thread = threading.Thread(socket_test(remote_ip, i))
        new_thread.start()
        threads.append(new_thread)

    [this_thread.join() for this_thread in threads]
```